# New-relic deamon still listed as service

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, newrelic

I am trying to remove newrelic completely from my system. I have followed their uninstall procedures, however, when running `service --status-all` i notice `[ - ] newrelic-deamon` is still on the list.

Also tried `sudo apt autoremove`

How can I remove it completely?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `apt-get remove --purge newrelic`?

Moreover everything you need to know about installation/uninstallation is documented here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/advanced-installation/uninstalling-php-agent